# Install Python 3.6.2 on Windows without admin rights

Tags: python

I am trying to install Python 3.6.2 on a windows vps I have but I need admin rights to do it.

I tried a various different methods but none of them worked.

There is no MSI version for python 3 so that does not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a windows vps with remote desktop being used to control it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might get me in trouble for suggesting thirdparty solutions, but Anaconda saved my bacon so many times in your situation, it's not even funny.

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/windows

Answer (score 0):

I found that i couldn't install the latest version for the same reasons you stated but if you select a previous version it will install fine.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
(assuming you are on windows)

This doesn't answer the question of how to install that version, but if you are happy with a previous version then, this could work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the embeddable version (Really a zipped portable version), but I'm not sure about dependencies management (i.e. pip) and path variables and whatnot.